# How to add text field like in sms (a label count the number of charterer left below ).in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In my application I insert a text field and I validate the text field if user exceed their character   limits I show a dialog.But Now a days like in (while sending sms or mail) there is label below text field  which count the number of left .Is this possible in jquery ? 
like here is my text field

```
<input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="caseName_h" autocorrect="off">
```

I am able to validate if text is greater then 10.But below label have problem..:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can you text field function keyup or key down .Find the length of character inserted .This length is subtracted from the definite length. here is an example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

$('#field').keyup(function() {
        var len = $(this).val().length;

        if (len >= 500) {
          $(this).val() = $(this).substring(0, 500);
        } else {            
          $('#check').text(500 - len);
        }
      });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this logic to display no of characters left after entering some text.

HTML:

```
 <textarea id="field"></textarea>
    <div id="charNum">500</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

$('#field').keydown(function() {
        var len = $(this).val().length;

        if (len >= 500) {
          $(this).val() = $(this).substring(0, 500);
        } else {            
          $('#charNum').text(500 - len);
        }
      });

});
```

Find the working demo here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S7FCH/13/)